# id de una vista a otra

Tags: php

Tengo un tabla llamada **automoviles** y **automovilesdoc**. Cada **automoviles** puede tener diferentes **automovilesdoc**
a la hora de crear un  **automovilesdoc** agrego el **id** del **automovil**

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo traer el id de mi tabla **automoviles** y compararla con el **id_automovil** para mostrar todos los dados si los id son iguales?

Quiero traer los datos de esta manera pero me marca este error

**Cotrolador:**

```
$this->load->model("Automobiles_model");
        $productos =$this->Automobiles_model->getUser($id);
        $datos['productos'] = $productos;

        $this->load->model("Project_model");
        $productos2 =array("data"=>$this->Automobilesdoc_model->getUsers());
        $datos['productos2'] = $productos2;
```

**Errores:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: automobile/editdocdes.php
Line Number: 19
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\views\automobile\editdocdes.php
Line: 19
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\controllers\automobile\Editdocdes.php
Line: 29
Function: view
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando PHP (Laravel) o que lenguaje?

Comment: codeigniter es php

Comment: Antes que te agarren a negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta, lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.